# changing layers of instantiated objects C#

Tags: c#, input, instantiation, layer

I'm using a script to give inputs to a gameObject depending on its name.

```
public KeyCode cavalryCall;
GameObject CohortA;
GameObject CohortB;
GameObject CohortC;
GameObject CohortD;

//List of configurations
void Start () {

    CohortA = GameObject.Find ("Cohort A");
    CohortB = GameObject.Find ("Cohort B");
    CohortC = GameObject.Find ("Cohort C");
    CohortD = GameObject.Find ("Cohort D");

    //A Input
    if (gameObject == CohortA) {     

        cavalryCall = KeyCode.Alpha4;
    }

    //B Input
    if (gameObject == CohortB) {

        cavalryCall = KeyCode.R;
    }

    //C Input
    if (gameObject == CohortC) {

        cavalryCall = KeyCode.F;
    }

    //D Input
    if (gameObject == CohortD) {

        cavalryCall = KeyCode.V;
    }
}
```

Then I use that input to start several coroutines for diferent inputs, one of them intantiates another gameObject and then changes that new object's layer.

```
KeyInput scriptBeholderKI;

//Script adquisition
void Start () {

    scriptKI = gameObject.GetComponent <KeyInput> ();
}

void Update () {

    //Key inputs
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (scriptKI.cavalryCall)) {

        StopAllCoroutines ();
        StartCoroutine (CavalryCall (0));
    }
}

IEnumerator CavalryCall (float Cavalrycall) {

    Instantiate (CavalryCohort, CavalryCohortSpawn.transform.position, CavalryCohortSpawn.transform.rotation);
    CavalryCohort.layer = CavalryCohortSpawn.layer;
    yield return null;
}
```

}

The problem is that the resultant layer went haywire, I have 4 layers:

-**Layer A** for the "**CavalryCohortSpawn**" which is children of "**CohortA**", when I press "**Alpha 4**", it spawns in **layer D**.

-**Layer B** for the "**CavalryCohortSpawn**" which is children of "**CohortB**", when I press "**R**", it spawns in **layer C**.

-**Layer C** for the "**CavalryCohortSpawn**" which is children of "**CohortC**", when I press "**F**", it spawns in **layer B**.

-**Layer D** for the "**CavalryCohortSpawn**" which is children of "**CohortD**", when I press "**V**", it spawns in **layer A**.

I only posted the fragments that are relevant, there are more input variables in the first script and more coroutines in the second that work perfectly.
Also if anyone knows a better way to change layers I would appreciate it :)

Comment: What do you mean by "went haywire"?  What is the expected output, and what did you get?  I am a bit unclear on the desired result and intended behaviour..

Comment: the result is that the final layer of the instantiated gameObject is not the one it should be. I suppose the problem is that I'm using the .layer wrong or it doesn't do what i think it does. What I'm trying to do here: "CavalryCohort.layer = CavalryCohortSpawn.layer;" is to make the instantiated object obtain the same layer as the spawnObject from where it comes out